# Como verificar se um link ainda existe e se ele pode se aberto em um iframe

Tags: jquery, iframe

Eu utilizo iframe no meu projeto pra abrir certos links de sites distintos! Esses links ficam armazenados em um banco de dados, porém fazem um progressão futura esses mesmos links podem ser alterados ou excluidos, logo eles deixaram de existir, portanto eu gostaria de saber se tem como verificar se o link ainda existe.

EX: Cadastrei o link hoje no *BD* e durante um mês o link ficou ativo, depois desse mês o link foi desativado por algum motivo, isso irá gerar um pequeno transtorno no meu projeto! Eu gostaria então de verificar se o link que eu cadastrei ainda está ativo sempre que ele for requisitado no *BD*.

Ai que entra a outra parte, como comentei na pergunta, eu abro os links no *iframe*, só que existe alguns sites que bloqueiam essa renderização dentro do *iframe*, o próprio Google e Twitter são exemplos disso. Gostaria então que ao mesmo tempo que verificasse o link o script verificasse se o link permite ser aberto dentro de um *iframe* e caso o link não exista mais ou ele não possa ser aberto em um *iframe* eu gostaria que redirecionasse a pagina pra outra informando que o link não existe!

Comment: Ivan, vc quer fazer isso no navegador via JavaScript ou do lado do servidor (*back end*)? No segundo caso, qual a plataforma/linguagem que está usando?

Comment: Gostaria de fazer isso pelo navegador mesmo!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O jeito mais simples e direto de testar testar se uma URL está "funcionando" é fazer uma requisição e verificar o status HTTP retornado. Qualquer coisa diferente de `200`, tal como erro `400` (não encontrado) ou `500` (erro no servidor), significa um problema.

Posso adiantar que provavelmente não será possível fazer isso pelo navegador. Há um grande problema, que é a política de segurança que não permite requisições Ajax para outros domínios via JavaScript.

Na verdade, a restrição de segurança pode ser contornado usando [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing), porém as páginas acessadas nos *iframe*s teriam que dar permissão explícita para o seu domínio.

Uma solução alternativa é criar um serviço no seu próprio servidor que faça uma requisição na URL que precisa ser testada e então retorne o status HTTP, funcionando assim como uma espécie de *proxy*.

Uma forma de implementar isso seria definir o `src` do `iframe` para uma página especial que verifica a disponibilidade da URL e então faz um redirecionamento.

Supondo que você use `PHP` no servidor (pode ser qualquer linguagem), poderia então criar uma página chamada `validar-url.php`. Essa página recebe como parâmetro um identificador para a URL de destino. Poderia então definir um `iframe` apontando para essa página, assim:

```html
<iframe src="validar-url.php?id=123">
```

Então na sua página `validar-url.php` teria uma lógica mais ou menos assim:

```php
$url = recuperarUrl($_GET['id']);
$status = verificarUrl($url);
if ($status == 200) {
    header("Location: $url");
} else {
    header("Location: pagina-de-erro-quando-url-nao-disponivel");
}
```

Poderia também usar o serviço com JavaScript via Ajax, caso queira implementar a lógica no navegador.

Comment: Precisaria também verificar se a página retorna aquele header que impede que seja usada em iframe (não lembro o header exato).

Comment: @bfavaretto Boa! É o `X-FRAME-OPTIONS`, certo?

Comment: o 302 também não seria um status válido do HTTP para ele ? caso ele esteja usando um redirecionamento.

Comment: @MuriloGambôa Depende do caso de uso, mas seu comentário é pertinente. Acredito que uma implementação real seria tenha que considerar as diferentes possibilidades como 301, 303, 304 e assim por diante. No entanto, nem sempre todos esses estados poderiam ser considerados sucesso neste contexto, afinal pode ser que o sistema não queira levar em conta redirecionamentos, para saber se é uma página de verdade.

Comment: entendo, muito obrigado :3